# .net mvc routing URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this in my RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "client1",
            url: "client1/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "client2",
            url: "client2/{controller}/{action}",/* updated parent folder to match route name */
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is in my view.

```
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
```

When I run my application it runs on http://localhost:50415/

However the ActionLinks render to:

```
{root}/client1 
{root}/client1/Home/About 
{root}/client1/Home/Contact
```

My expectation was for the actionlinks to render like this:

```
{root}
{root}/Home/About
{root}/Home/Contact
```

So why was the client1 inserted for my links when I am running from http://localhost:50415/ ??

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing rules in MVC are processed in order. The first rule is the one that gets matched first. To solve this, just re-order the rules in your code. Also you can collapse the "client" rules into a single one by using constraints:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "client",
    url: "{client}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { client = "client1|client2" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: This does fix the problem that I asked about above, but then when I go to http://localhost:50415/client1 it tells me the resource cannot be found. This application will have multiple clients and I want most of them using a URL with their client name. Any ideas on a fix for this?